# Topological group homeomorphic

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

Exists a topological group homeomorphic to $(0, 1)$? and to $[0, 1]$?
I believe that with includes the extremes is it, to contrary than when they aren't included.
I tried to use the definition of topological group, but I'm not sure how to distinguish the two cases because of the extremes.

Comment: $(0,1)$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ via the function $x\mapsto \arctan(2x-1)$.

$\mathbb{R}$ is a topological group under addition.

Comment: @PatrickNicodemus and is for $[0, 1]$ the same?

Comment: $[0,1]$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, because $[0,1]$ is compact and $\mathbb{R}$ is not. I don't know if $[0,1]$ admits a topological group structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$[0,1]$ is not homeomorphic to a topological group. To see why, note that the left multiplication action of a topological group on itself is transitive, and it follows that the complements of any two points are homeomorphic. But the complement of each endpoint of $[0,1]$ is connected whereas the complement of each interior point is disconnected.

As said in the comment of @PatrickNicodemus, $(0,1)$ is homeomorphic to the topological group $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by @Patrick, $(0,1)$ is homeomorphic to ${\mathbb R}$.

However $[0, 1]$ is not homeomorphic to any topological group
because every topological group $G$ is homogeneous,  that is,  for any two points $g$ and $h$ in $G$,  there is a
homeomorphism of $G$ sending $g$ to $h$,  namely left-multiplication by $hg^{-1}$.

However there is no homeomorphism
from $[0,1]$ to itself sending $0$ to $1/2$.